# Determining what apps are being used to spy over my screen

Tags: applications, security

I would like to know whether there is a way to determine whether someone is looking at my phone screen while I use my phone.

I ask because I once had a pop-up window and granted access, but I don't know what that window was.

Now I want to find out.

Thanks.

Comment: The only way I know for an app to get access of data shown in a different app is registering itself as accessibility helper app. The list of accessibility helper apps can be found in Android settings.